# Best way to send events via webhooks twice?

Tags: go, architecture, webhooks

In this problem scenario, **organisation** **A** generates the webhooks and sends it to **organisation B**, **organisation B** in turn sends it **only** to the proper destination organisation. The webhooks cannot be sent directly from **organisation A** to the destination organisation.

[image]

What would be the best architecture to follow for implementing such a scenario? I'm using Golang to implement this system

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it fits `pub/sub` model.

Can webhook from **organisation A** abstract as any message?

You can use Redis pub/sub or other MQ middleware (like RabbitMQ, Kafka) instead of **organisation B**.

Destination organisations subscribe to **organisation B**'s message.